# Python: TerminalでTabのインデントができない

Tags: python

Teminalでpythonのインタプリターを立ち上げてTabでインデントをしようとすると、
Tabが補完されずに、以下のようになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

bashの設定かと思うのですが、
bash_profileの設定は、

```
export PYENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.pyenv"
export PATH=${PYENV_ROOT}/bin:$PATH
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

としています。

Tabでインデント補完できるように戻したいのですが、
どのように設定すればいいでしょうか。

ご教授、宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

それはbashの問題ではなく、Python3のインタラクティブシェルの機能です。Python2のシェルにtabを押してみたら、ちゃんとインデントしました。

でも、インデントする時、tabの代わりに、スペースを使うべきです。（[PEP8 Tabs or spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)にご参考）

そして、インタラクティブシェルに複雑のコードの書くのは、いろいろ不便ですので、[IPython](http://qiita.com/5t111111/items/7852e13ace6de288042f)というツールを勧めます。

Answer (score 0):

python -S で起動するか、
以下のようなスクリプトを作成し、`$PYTHONSTARTUP` にそのスクリプト名を指定してください。

```
import sys

def register_readline_custom():
    import readline
    readline.read_init_file()
    readline.parse_and_bind('tab: tab-insert')

sys.__interactivehook__ = register_readline_custom

del sys
```

これはデフォルト設定を無思慮に上書きしますので、デフォルトが気になる場合は
https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/site.py
の `register_readline()` を見てください(タブキーを補完にし、履歴の設定をしているだけです)。

個人的にはインタラクティブシェルで使用するなら ipython をおすすめしますが。